# word movement behaviour on different variable naming schemes

Tags: vim

Is there an option or extension available to change the behavior of w (and the similar e,b..) depending on the current variable naming scheme being used?

So for example moving between words in camelCase, under_score and so on convenctions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next plugin: [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905)